# Is there a way to separate the real and the imaginary parts of the roots of a polynomial without knowing the roots of the polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Given a first polynomial, is it possible to construct a second polynomial whose roots are only the imaginary (or likewise, only the real) parts of the roots of the first polynomial **without knowing the roots of the first polynomial**?

I think it is not possible, but I am interested in hearing your thoughts on this.

Comment: It is possible, but not very practical. Taking as an example the polynomial $\,p(z)=z^3-1\,$, let $\,z=x+iy\,$ then equating the real and imaginary parts to $0$ and eliminating $\,y\,$ between the two equations using polynomial [resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) gives [resultant(x^3 - 3xy^2 - 1, 3x^2y - y^3, y)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%28a%5E3-3ab%5E2+-+1%2C+3a%5E2b+-+b%5E3%2C+b%29) $\,q(x)=(x^3 - 1) (8 x^3 + 1)^2$. The *real* roots of $q(x)$ are the real parts of the roots of $p(x)$, in this case $\{1, -1/2\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with a normalized polynomial of second degree $p(z)=(z-z_1)(z-z_2)$.

If we know the roots of the first polynomial, we can formulate the second polynomial

$$g(z)=\left(z-\dfrac{z_1+\overline{z}_1}{2}\right) \left(z-\dfrac{z_2+\overline{z}_2}{2}\right).$$

The overline designates the complex conjugate.
If you expand this expression you will see that there is not an simple expression depending on $p(z)$.

Hence, I would conclude that it is not possible to do what you asked for. You can try a similar approach for the imaginary part of the roots with $(z-\overline{z})/2$ for the imaginary part of the corresponding root. Only the trivial linear polynomial allows this procedure because we directly know the roots.

Comment: If $p(z)=z^2+az+b$, then $g(z)=z^2+a'z+b'$, where $a'=\mathrm{Re}(a)$, $b=\frac{4\mathrm{Re}(a)+|a|^2-|a^2-4b|}{8}$.