# Is it any easier to determine if a zero of a polynomial is on the critical circle instead of a Riemann zeta zero on the critical line?

Tags: polynomials, roots, riemann-zeta, roots-of-unity, riemann-hypothesis

The Dirichlet eta function is:

$$\eta (s) = \zeta (s) (1-2^{1-s})$$
$$\eta (s) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^{s}}$$

Notice that:

$$\log(k)=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\text{Round}[n \log (k)]}{n}$$

$$k^{s} = (e^{\log(k)})^{s}$$

$$k^{s}=\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} {\left(e^{\frac{\text{Round}[n \log (k)]}{n}}\right)^{s}}$$
so that the Dirichlet eta function becomes:

$$\eta (s) = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{\left(e^{\frac{\text{Round}[n \log (k)]}{n}}\right)^{s}}$$

or alternatively:
$$\eta (s) = \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{\left(e^{\frac{\text{Round}[n \log (k)]}{n}}\right)^{s}}$$

Solving $\text{the 
Right Hand Side}=0$ for $s$:

$$n \left(2 \pi  i C-\log \left(\text{Root}\left[\sum _{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} s^{\text{Round}[n \log (k)]}\right]\right)\right)$$

Since we in the Riemann hypothesis are interested only in the real part, we can discard the integer multiples $C$ of $2 \pi  i$:

$$-n \log \text{Root}\left[\sum _{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} s^{\text{Round}[n \log (k)]}\right]$$

Without the logarithm we then have the $m-th$ root as:

$$z_{m} = \text{Root}\left[\sum _{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} s^{\text{Round}[n \log (k)]}\right]$$

Substituting $s \rightarrow x$ and considering only the remaining polynomial we then have:

$$P(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k+1} x^{\text{Round}[n \log (k)]}$$

or alternatively:

$$P(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1} x^{\text{Round}[n \log (k)]}$$

---

If we compute $-n\log(z_m)$ where $m=\text{Round}\left[\log(n)n\frac{3}{4}\right]..\text{Round}\left[\log(n)n\right]$, of the polynomial:

$$P(x) = \sum _{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} x^{\text{Round}[n \log (k)]} \tag{$*$}$$

we see that the roots cluster in the complex plane around the vertical line with real parts: $$\Re(-n\log(z_j)) \approx \frac{1}{2}$$ and $$\Re(-n\log(z_t)) \approx 1$$ (for some $j \in m$ and $t \in m$) as can be seen in this plot for the polynomial for $n=500$:

[image: logarithm of roots of polynomial for n = 500]

```
(*Mathematica 8 start*)
nn = 100;
n = nn;(*Increase n=500 for better precision*)
$MaxRootDegree = Round[Log[n]*n] + 1;
Monitor[z = 
   Table[(N[
      Root[Sum[(-1)^(k + 1)*#1^Round[(Log[k]*n)], {k, 1, n}] &, 
       m]]), {m, Round[Log[n]*n*3/4], Round[Log[n]*n]}];, n]
ListPlot[Chop[
  Table[{Re[-nn*Log[z[[n]]]], Im[-4/Pi*Log[z[[n]]]]}, {n, 1, 
    Length[z]}]]]
ListPlot[Chop[Table[{Re[z[[n]]], Im[z[[n]]]}, {n, 1, Length[z]}]], 
 AspectRatio -> 4]
(*end*)
```

The imaginary part of the logarithm of the zeros is multiplied with minus four divided by $\pi$ as: $\Im\left(-\frac{4}{\pi}\log(z_i)\right)$ so that the plot is normalized to height one.

The polynomial roots without taken the logarithm of, form a *quarter* segment of a circle:

[image: right quarter segment of roots circle]

If the we instead plot the logarithm of *all* the polynomial zeros $-n\log(z_m)$ for $n=100$ and $m=1..\text{Round}\left[\log(n)n\right]$  we get a more spread out plot:

[image: logarithm of all the polynomial zeros for n=100]

and a complete but rough circle (when plotting the roots $z_m$ of the polynomial $P(x)$ in $(*)$ directly, and not taking logarithms of them):

[image: polynomial roots for n = 100]

Now since there is the *Theorem 1.1.* for polynomials of even degree in the pdf notes by Keith Conrad at:
https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/numbersoncircle.pdf

**Theorem 1.1.** Let $f(z) \in \mathbb{Q}\left[z\right]$ be irreducible with degree $n > 1$. If $f(z)$ has a root on the unit circle then $n$ is even and $z^n f(1/z) = f(z)$,

> I will ask if such theorems can be used to prove that one or several roots of the polynomial in $(*)$:
> $$P(x) = \sum _{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} x^{\text{Round}[n \log (k)]}$$ lie on the **critical circle** when $n \rightarrow \infty$, instead of
> the **critical line** as in the Riemann hypothesis?

The radius of the critical circle should yet be computed. This builds upon the answer by Professor Jeffrey Stopple at MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/a/398389/25104

---

Any rational approximation $p/q$ of $\log(k)$ will do, but this one above I figured is the fastest. I have also considered using truncated Dirichlet series expansions of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic: $\sum_{d|k} \Lambda(d) = \log(k) $, where $\Lambda(n)=\lim\limits_{s \rightarrow 1} \zeta(s)\sum\limits_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^{(s-1)}}$. In that way one gets several separate lines in the root plot in the complex plane, instead of a root cloud clustering around $\Re(-n\log(s)) = 1/2$.

---

But why does `SumConvergence[(-1)^(k + 1)*x^Log[k], k]` give
`1 + Log[Abs[x]] < 0`?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4292657/8530

Comment: I feel this question needs to be focused quite a bit.